# Random value in php using array_rand

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have two values: `#FFF` & `#000`

I want to echo randomly anyone, for that I tried:

```
$color = array('#FFF','#000');
$color = array_rand($color);
$color = $color[$color];
echo $color;
```

But it doesn't display anything.

Comment: `$color = $color[$color];` seems strange. Don't you think that somewhere somehow you overwrite one value with another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must need to take care of 2 things,

One, if you overwrite the variable with same name then, it will not produce your desired result.

Second, [`array_rand()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) will generate the random key

Why your code is not working, because, your initial array is `$color`:

```
$color = array('#FFF','#000');
```

After this, you are using [`array_rand()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php), which will give random key

```
$color = array_rand($color);
```

Now, your `$color` is overwrite from array to integer value. it means when you try to access `$color[$color]` this will give you nothing because, its not defined or overwritten.

**Solution:** just change your variable name specially array. using proper variable name is a good approach and this will help to others who will work on your work after you.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$colorArray = array('#FFF','#000');
$colorKey = array_rand($colorArray);
$colorName = $colorArray[$colorKey];
echo $colorName;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Capture random index in other variable let say `$key`.

```
$color = array('#FFF','#000');
$key =  array_rand($color);
echo $color[$key];
```

> **Note:**   array_rand — Pick one or more random keys out of an array

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/lq6GA)

Comment: Priority wise I accepted your answer but keeping in mind future readers I accepted another answer having a full explanation! Voted up

Answer (score 1):

You had a good idea using [array_rand](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php)

> array_rand — Pick one or more random keys out of an array

However you are overwriting your array. (**$color**)

Try that instead :

```
$arrayRand = array_rand($color);
$randomColor= $color[$arrayRand];
```